# Onclick on textview late respond

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I have an onclick function text view, but it takes 3 to 4 seconds to respond.

The layout code related with the TextView:

```
<TableRow ... >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/questionReportSelectTV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="15dip"
    android:paddingTop="15dip"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="showImageActivity"
    android:textSize="17sp" />

</TableRow>
```

Inflating the layout:

```
LayoutInflater inflaterQuestion = getLayoutInflater(); 
TableRow trQuestion= (TableRow) inflaterQuestion.inflate(R.layout.questionreportrow, setTaleLayout, false); 
LayoutInflater inflaterSpace = getLayoutInflater(); 
TableRow trSpace = (TableRow) inflaterSpace.inflate(R.layout.space_tablerow, setTaleLayout, false);
TextView questionDisplay = (TextView)trQuestion.findViewById(R.id.questionReportSelectTV); 
questionDisplay.setTypeface(typeFace); 
questionDisplay.setText(pn); 
questionDisplay.setTag(counterPosition);
```

Action on button click:

```
public void showImageActivity(View view){ 
   int tvTag = (Integer) view.getTag(); 
   Intent imageIntent = new Intent(ReportExamSelectQuestionActivity.this, DisplayImageActivity.class);
   imageIntent.putExtra("POSITION", tvTag); 
   startActivity(imageIntent); 
}
```

Comment: Are you using emulator to test your app?

Comment: No, i am not.... LayoutInflater inflaterQuestion = getLayoutInflater();
    TableRow  trQuestion= (TableRow) inflaterQuestion.inflate(R.layout.questionreportrow,
      setTaleLayout, false);
    
    
    LayoutInflater inflaterSpace = getLayoutInflater();
    TableRow trSpace = (TableRow) inflaterSpace.inflate(R.layout.space_tablerow, setTaleLayout, false);
    
    TextView questionDisplay = (TextView)trQuestion.findViewById(R.id.questionReportSelectTV);
    questionDisplay.setTypeface(typeFace);
    questionDisplay.setText(pn);
    questionDisplay.setTag(counterPosition);

Comment: Please add your showImageActivity method code to the question.

Comment: :)) @AbdulBaais I mean what are you using to test your app with?
Are you using emalator or a real device or sth else?

Comment: I am Using OnePlus One Device, public void showImageActivity(View view){ int tvTag = (Integer) view.getTag(); Intent imageIntent = new Intent(ReportExamSelectQuestionActivity.this, DisplayImageActivity.class); imageIntent.putExtra("POSITION", tvTag); startActivity(imageIntent); }

Comment: try to test it on other devices and compare the delay time.
you can also put some logs before and after your code in showImageActivity() and log the current time in shows you the delay time. I dont think the problem is with your onclick or your code. I just guess it might be related to your device you are using.test it on other devices.

Comment: It seems to me that `DisplayImageActivity.class` is performing too much on its UI thread. Can you post its code by editing your post?

Comment: It is not only, a one OnClick, all the onclick on that Activity are late to respond. Onclick those are not DisplayImageActivity.class also take time to resposnf

Answer (score 0):

Your TextView is normal. Maybe something wrong is in showImageActivity function that takes time to response.

As a test, show a toast at the first line of your function to check response delay.

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;

public class Activity1 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity1_layout);
}

public void showImageActivity(View v)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Here write your codes about Showing image...
}
}
```

Comment: public void showImageActivity(View view){
  
  
  int tvTag = (Integer) view.getTag();
  Intent imageIntent =  new Intent(ReportExamSelectQuestionActivity.this, DisplayImageActivity.class);
  
  imageIntent.putExtra("POSITION", tvTag);
  startActivity(imageIntent);
  
 }
This is my activity, I am testing using a device. I checked with TOAST too, it takes the same amount of time

Comment: You should only place that Toast in it. Nothing else.